# What is it called when you lose a tooth but still have most remaining ones?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I know the word *toothless* means, according to Google:

> *having no teeth, typically through old age.*

I'm wondering if a kid or an adult loses one or two teeth is also called *toothless*. As I understand it, toothless means *having no teeth*, not *losing some teeth.*

What is it called when someone loses a teeth or two due to the process of growing up, or an accident, or something else. But they still have a number of teeth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Literally, [***gap-toothed***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gap-toothed) -

> having a large space between two teeth

It's not endearing, and you probably wouldn't use it to describe a child in positive terms.  It's often used as part of a description of a decrepit person.

A child's usually just "losing his/her teeth" unless you want a vivid depiction of a "gap-toothed smile."