# Word for: Someone who has lost, and cannot grow back, their front teeth

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

In Semitic languages (notably Arabic, Old Hebrew, and Amharic), there is an adjective to describe someone who has lost their front teeth, typically in an accident or a fight, and **can't grow them back** (so not a child just shedding their teeth). So someone who has got one or more limbs chopped off is called an ***amputee***, an animal that got its teeth pulled out is ***defanged***, a person who lost two or more teeth in a fight or an accident is called ___?

Comment: @user66974 - They are all variations of "Athram" or "Ataram"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is it called when you lose a tooth but still have most remaining ones?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262931/what-is-it-called-when-you-lose-a-tooth-but-still-have-most-remaining-ones)

Answer (score 2):

No.  There is no word in English for such a person.  Similarly, Yiddish has a word for the relationship between the mothers of a husband and wife, where there is no such word in English (other than the painful co-mothers-in-law), which I have never heard used.  Languages differ so that it is not alway possible to match a word in one language with a corresponding word in another.  It is one of the interesting things about languages.